# increment an integer via linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to increment an int value via linq. Suppose the int value is `4354764` & I want to increase it 500 more values. I know I can do it via for loop, but is it possible via LINQ ?

Example :

```
int counter = 4354764;
var query = from a in stuff
            select new { count = counter++ };
```

In the above example, I want to increase the counter 500 times & want to get the query variable as integer with increased value.

Comment: Why? What is the purpose of this? What is `stuff`? Why 500 times? Are there 500 items in `stuff`?

Comment: 1 question, why???????

Comment: Nothing, it is just an example. There is nothing like stuff. I just have counter variable which needs to be increased 500 times.

Comment: Ah, that point where LINQ forces you to come back and read about closures and variable capture :)

Comment: If you want to increase the variable 500 times, you could write
    `for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    {
      ++counter;
    }`
but the usual way of writing that would be
    `counter += 500;`. If you insist on using LINQ, add `using System.Linq` to the top of the file :P Are you sure this is not an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you really wanted to ask something else?

Comment: I said I can do it via for loop but wanted to use LINQ or Lambda expression!! @CompuChip

Comment: But why? It sounds like "I know how to use a hammer but I wanted to fix this nail using my swiss army knife."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Enumberable.Range` and rely on side-effects to increase `counter`. Please note that LINQ uses lazy evaluation and therefor you need to force evaluation of the query for `counter` to be increased. I have used `ToList()`, however, you can also use `Count()` as suggested by FredrikRedin.

```
 int counter = 4354764;
 var query = (from a in Enumerable.Range(1, 500)
                select new { count = counter++ }).ToList();
```

Or alternatively:-)

```
counter += 500
```

Or if you really need a range:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(counter, counter + 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

I’ve adapted your example and added the 500 iterations

```
int counter = 4354764;
int result  = Enumerable.Range(1, 500)
                        .Select(x => ++counter)
                        .Last();

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", counter, result);
```

Since `.Last()` forces total enumeration, this outputs

```
4355264 4355264
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from a in Enumerable.Range(1, 500) select new { count = counter + a };
```

Comment: How to get the integer value ?

Comment: Then new `count` value!!

Comment: There are 500 anonymous objects, right? You can access them.

Comment: `int newCounter = 4354764+500;`

Answer (score 1):

Count() is sufficient to force evalutation, no need to create list.

```
 int counter = 10;
 Enumerable.Range(1, 500).Select(x => ++counter).Count();
 Console.WriteLine("{0}", counter);
```